# Compound poisson distribution

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution

The number of quarterly claims an insurance company receives is represented by a random variable $N$ which is poisson distributed at a rate $\lambda \in (0, \infty)$.

With each claim received, let $p \in (0,1)$ be the probability that a related claim is received during the next quarter.

Determine the range and the pmf of the random variable $X$ which represents the number of related claims received in the next quarter. What distribution does $X$ follow?

---

I think by definition X follows a compound poisson distribution, and I would say the range is $(N(\lambda), \infty)$, but any ideas on how to determine the pmf of X?

Comment: Assuming $T$ to be the time of "the next quarter," $X$ simply has $\mathsf{Pois}(p\lambda  T)$ distribution. That is, splitting a Poisson process in this manner yields two independent Poisson processes.

Comment: @Math1000 I would assume $\lambda$ was an expected number per quarter so $T=1$.  But I would ask what about new unrelated claims: are they a component of $X$?

Comment: @Henry No they are not, I now corrected it in the original post

Comment: If the possibility of a related claim for one original claim is independent of the others then I would have thought you cannot have more than $N$ related claims.   Though if you regard $N$ as potentially unbounded, that may not be a constraint on the marginal distribution of $X$

Comment: I am going to assume that it is indeed independent of the other claims ( since otherwise it can't be a Poisson distribution ), why wouldn't there be more than N related claims ?

Comment: Oh, I misread the problem as the claims following a *Poisson process.* Never mind.

Comment: zartos: Each of the $N$ original claims may or may not produce a related claim so, conditional on $N$, the number of related claims is at least $0$ but no more than $N$.